# How to fix skewed unwrapping

Tags: uv

When I try to unwrap a simple cube object, the UV is shown skewed. I guess it has to do with the object rotation. But I don't know how to fix it.

[image: skewed unwrapping]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU6Foc3mfrs) by Expose Academy, it happens when 2 dimensions of your object are similar and with some UV seams configurations. To fix it, align two of your vertices with the snap option, pin these 2 vertices, unwrap again:

[image]